# SQL Server Reporting Services: Limit Legend to One Series for Chart that has Multiple Series

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008, charts

I have a chart with these characteristics:

- chart type is XY (scatter )
- all XY data have x-values that are integers; they are called "Update Cycle" numbers. This represents "score" data from a given program.
- in addition to the values that produce the XY data, I've added two other elements to the "Values:" list: one that is the average of the XY data for any Update Cycle (x-axis) value, and another that is the average of "similar programs" for any Update Cycle. These elements are plotted as lines ("trend lines") on the chart.
- Category Group is Update Cycle number
- Series Group are (1) PersonID and (2) ProgramID

It all plots fine, but here's my problem:

If I add a Legend, it wants to add Legend entries for each and every point for each and every person (because of SeriesGroup1)  - I imagine it's also showing legend entries for the second series, but there are so many for the first series, I can't read anything.

Question: How do I supress legend entries for the first series and only display the two legend entries for the 2nd series?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, Is any solutions for the series text overlaping?, I found a solutions, but I cann't use, because divided the chart in various charts, by the way, heres is the link of the article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/841e1515-3519-4c4f-a76f-f6fcebd25dfd/

If somebody have another solutions, pleace post it.

Thanks and sorry, my English is a little poor.